# propertychange event to trigger on Page load

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I am using textarea and I have binded propertychange event to it. Below is the code I used

```
$('#textareaID').bind('input propertychange', function() {});
```

But this event gets triggers only when changes happen to the textarea after the page loads. I want it to get triggered when page loads itself. Since on page load I am assigning a value where I want it to happen at that time. Is it possible to trigger at page load itself ?

Comment: You have to wait at least until the DOM loads.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Does triggering it manually work for you?

Example in jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/VAT83/

```
$(function() {
    var textValue = $('#textValue');        
    $('#textareaID')
         .bind('input propertychange', function() {
             textValue.html($(this).val());
         })
         .trigger('propertychange');
});​
```